# Sum Totals in a 3rd column from other columns using conditional formatting

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010

I am working with excel 2010 attendance work sheet. Column B is `Date`, Column C is `Points`. 
Column B has conditional formatting to highlight dates based on a revolving year, the two conditions are:

- Formula =ISBLANK(B3)=TRUE
- Cell Value greater than =TODAY()-365 to fill with yellow.

Column C is based on Points, the conditional format is:

- Formula =B3>TODAY()-365 Highlight to yellow.

I need Column C the `Totals Column` to sum only those point numbers that are within the `=B3>TODAY()-365` range. We are currently entering one cell in manually by simply counting them.

I was not able to yellow the cells in this example typed here, but if they were colored it would be `5/22/2013`, `6/17/2013` and `7/30/13`, as well as the corresponding numbers in the `POINTS` column. I do want to sum by fill color.

```
Joe Blow
REASON                                DATE            POINTS        TOTALS
Tardy-Work>5 hours-leave early       3/10/3012         0.5            3
With 2 week notification-unpaid      4/12/2013           1
With 2 week notification-unpaid      5/22/2013           1
Ill                                  6/17/2013           1
Tardy-Work<5 hours-report late       7/30/2013           1
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">"&TODAY()-365)
```